# How to specify version of bundler for bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, bundler

When I try to bundle the gemfile of a new project I get :

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler-audit was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
      bundler (~> 1.2)

    rails (~> 5.2) was resolved to 5.2.1, which depends on
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.0.2)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 1.2)', which is required by gem 'rails (~>
5.2)', in any of the sources.
```

As a result I run `gem install bundler '~> 1.2'`. 
Now when I run `gem list bundler`, I have those 2 versions 2.0.2, 1.17.3
I know want to bundle my gemfile with version 1.17.3 
However when I run `bundle _1.17.3_ install`, I get :
`Could not find command "_1.17.3_"`.
What am I doing wrong here ? How can I fix that ? Is there a way to specify directly in my rails project with which version of bundler it should download & resolve dependencies ?

Comment: Hi, Do you already have a Gemfile.loc file? If so, what's version of bundler at the end of Gemfile.loc ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `gem install bundler -v 1.17.3` and then `bundle _1.17.3_ install`